# Unable to use jQuery.Validation to validate a SELECT array AND within a group

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation

Having searched, I've found similar questions that deal with SELECT arrays OR Require_From_Group, but nothing utilising both, and can't seem to get both working together.

The code is (currently) thus:

```
<form id="frmMeeting" ...>
    <select name="internal_attendees[]" id="internal_attendees" size="6" class="attendees attendee-group" multiple="multiple"></select> 
    <select name="external_attendees[]" id="external_attendees" size="6" class="attendees attendee-group" multiple="multiple"></select> 
</form>

<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

var validator = $("#frmMeeting").validate({
    errorElement: "span",
    rules: {
        'internal_attendees[]': {
            require_from_group: [1, ".attendee-group"]
        },
        'external_attendees[]': {
            require_from_group: [1, ".attendee-group"]
        }
    }
});
```

I have changed the jQuery.validate.js as per another question to allow validation of arrays:

```
checkForm: function() {
    this.prepareForm();
    for (var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++ ) {
        if (this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length != undefined && this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length > 1) {
            for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length; cnt++) {
                this.check( this.findByName( elements[i].name )[cnt] );
            }
        } else {
            this.check( elements[i] );
        }
    }
    return this.valid();
}
```

I have tried various combinations and answers to validate the group but wonder whether the challenge is that it is a SELECT array rather than an INPUT array.

Currently receiving the correct "Please fill at least 1 of these fields." message against the two fields BUT I can't seem to get it to pass validation (even when both SELECTs have data) in them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that require_from_group only checks if elements have a value:

```
isValid = $fields.filter( function() {
        return validator.elementValue( this );
        } ).length >= options[ 0 ];
```

An empty array will return true e.g. `Boolean([])`, so an html `<select multiple="multiple">` is treated as always filled. Therefore, the whole require_from_group validates to true.

To fix it I replaced the built in require_from_group with this tweaked version: https://gist.github.com/RegisFrey/d260c1c150ab398b6231790b23a6fffc